# Analytical Proof of the statement: $n! > n^{100}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, cauchy-sequences

I think intuitively $n! > n^{100}$, this does not work for values of $n<126$. It is clear that after $n=126$ the sequence $n!$ grows faster than $n^{100}$.

I am trying to give an analytical proof of the statement.

**Attempt**: Let $a_n = \frac{n!}{n^{100}}$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = n+1$ and this diverges. I am not sure if this suffices to conclude that $n!>n^{100}$.

I am sure there is a simpler way to prove this but I can't figure how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $n! >n^a$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (for sufficiently large $n$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907573/how-to-prove-n-na-for-all-a-in-mathbbr-for-sufficiently-large-n)

Comment: "$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = n+1$" means nothing. The RHS should not depend on $n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes thank you.

Comment: You can write that as: $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim n+1.$$

Comment: I was thinking of that but then how do you come to the conclusion that $n! > n^{100}$?